# Дана строка, состоящая из символов букв и цифр Между словами вставить запятую и пробел

Tags: c++

символы буквы и цифры ввести в командной строке. помогите пожалуйста
не могу вывести в командной строке символы итд

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

void change(string &str);
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str,s1;
    cout << "str:";
        getline(cin, str);

    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') 
            str.insert(i, ", ");
        cout << str << s1 << endl;
    }
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

void change(string &str);
using namespace std;

int main() {
 string str,s1;
 cout << "str:";
  getline(cin, str);

 for (string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
  if (str[i] == ' ') 
   str.insert(i, ", ");
  cout << str << s1 << endl;
 }
     _getch();
  return 0;
 }

Comment: Нажмите на кнопку Править https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1512258/edit и вставьте исходный код в текст вопроса.

Comment: проблема в том что не могу вывести в командной строке символы итд

Comment: вот код, и попал в тупик

Answer (score 0):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что Вы попадаете в бесконечный цикл:
Каждый раз, когда Вы попадаете на пробел, Вы:

- увеличиваете длину строки
- добавляете еще один пробел, который Вам в будущем придется еще раз обрабатывать, а при его обработке Вы еще раз добавите еще один пробел, который в последствии придется обрабатывать и так далее...

Действуете проще:
Вам нужно выводить

1. выводите в цикле посимвольно
2. перед пробелом выводите запятую

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str,s1;
    cout << "str:";
    getline(cin, str);

    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') { cout << ','; }
        cout << str[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Я ни разу не `C++` разработчик, но мне кажется, что такое решение Вам может подойти

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все работает спасибо, но нужно в командной строке без пробела вводить, а выводить с пробелом

Answer (score 0):

```
string str;
   cout << "str:";
       getline(cin, str);
       int size=str.size();
   for (int i = 0; i<size; ++i) 
       if (str[i] == ' ') 
           {str.insert(i,", ");
           i+=2;}//тк старый пробел сместился на 2 вперед, то мы к нему же и идем, чтобы быть на исходной позиции
   cout<<str;}
```